# PHP-класс для работы с изображениями

Tags: php

Всем привет.

Возник такой вопрос при выборе класса для работы с изображениями на php. Нашел следующие классы: WideImage, Smart Image Resizer, PHP Thumb. Мне нужно использовать изображение в разных форматах: оригинальное, 60x60, оригинальное с уменьшенными размерами и качеством (около 20-40 кб).

Приглянулся второй класс - Smart Image Resizer. Он довольно легкий в использовании, но его вес составляет около 3 МБ. В работе его очень удобно использовать:

```
<img src="/slir/w100-h100/path/to/image.jpg" />
```

У данного класса используются параметры в адресной строке - это нормально? Но я не уверен, практичен ли этот класс. Как-то странно работает. Кто-нибудь пользовался этим классом? Какие другие классы можете подсказать?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А что не нормального если вы используя GET просите у скрипта сделать изображение согласно пути к этому изображению?

То что он весит 3 метра, это естественно не нормально!

Зачем использовать класс, если можно сделать простенький скрипт обращаясь к которому он будет делать тоже самое?

Comment: Я думаю такой скрипт удобнее в использование. =) А какие можете посоветовать?

Comment: @Nick удобство и практичность две разные вещи! Мне интересно в чем он удобен? Он выполняет многозадачность? Или еще какие процедуры которые требуют именно использовать класс а не простенький правильный скрипт? Или класс потому что это класс а не просто какой то там скрипт?)

Comment: Удобно в том, что при работе с изображением достаточно загрузить одно оригинальное изображение и можно не создавая копий манипулировать им. Из этого изображения через ссылку создать уменьшенную копию и т.д.
Если я не ошибаюсь, такое делать через простенький класс нельзя.

Comment: Какие можете посоветовать классы ил личной практики?

Comment: создавать налету фотки - глупо, тем более если это постоянно.
Проще один раз создать уменьшенную копию и показывать её по нормальной ссылке!

Comment: В соседней ветке обсуждали http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/introduction . Посмотрите, на вид довольно удобный, интегрируется с Laravel при необходимости.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Какие можете посоветовать классы ил
> личной практики?
>
> Приглянулся второй класс - Smart Image
> Resizer. Он довольно легкий в
> использовании, но его вес составляет
> около 3 МБ.

[Smart Image Resizer](http://shiftingpixel.com/2008/03/03/smart-image-resizer/) 12,9KB. Я не поленился и затер все что закомментировано, в итоге получилось 7,39KB. но никак не 3MB, и совсем не class)

Comment: Вы нашли версию 1.4.1 . Я же нашел SLIR 2.0 - она действительно 2.8 мб весит.

Оптимально ли использовать этот ли скрипт, так скажем? Или же можете посоветовать что-нибудь другое?

Answer (score 2):

[Обработка изображений (ImageMagick)](http://ru.php.net/manual/ru/book.imagick.php)

> Imagick является встроенным
> php-расширением для создания и
> изменения изображений используя API
> ImageMagick.
>
> ImageMagick® представляет собой набор
> программного обеспечения для создания,
> редактирования и компонования
> растровых изображений.. Он может
> читать, конвертировать и записывать
> изображения в различных форматах
> (более 100), включая DPX, EXR, GIF,
> JPEG, JPEG-2000, PDF, PhotoCD, PNG,
> Postscript, SVG, и TIFF.

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Посмотрю. )